# How to use qiskit to build an qnn classifier which uses cross_entropy and only an one qubit observable?

Tags: qiskit

From qiskit documentation, I only find EstimatorQNN can edit observables. But I don't know how to use cross_entropy in EstimatorQNN. I only want to observe the last qubit.